# Dune not able to compile my first project

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I followed the following steps to create my project

1. Create the project using the following dune command

   dune init proj --kind=lib mymaps
2. Then added 2 files under the "lib" directory

mymaps.mli

```
type ('k, 'v) t
val empty : ('k, 'v) t
val insert : 'k -> 'v -> ('k, 'v) t -> ('k, 'v) t
```

mymaps.ml

```
type ('k, 'v) t = ('k * 'v) list
let rec insert k v m = match m with 
  | [] -> [(k, v)]
  | (eK, eV) :: tl -> let (nK, nV) = if (eK = k) then (k, v) else (eK, eV) in 
                    (nK, nV) :: insert k v tl
let empty = []
```

3. Added the following file under the "tests" directory

mymaps_tests.ml

```
open Ounit2
open Mymaps
let empty_test = 
  "empty has no bindings" >:: (fun _ -> assert_equal [] (empty));
let mymap_tests = [empty_test]
let suite = "maps suite" >::: mymap_tests
let _ = run_test_tt_main suite
```

However when I go to command line and say `dune build` it says

```
File "test/dune", line 2, characters 7-13:
2 |  (name mymaps))
       ^^^^^^
Error: Module "Mymaps" doesn't exist.
```

Here is the link to GitHub for my work https://github.com/abhsrivastava/mymaps

I am following a tutorial on YouTube and I didn't see them implement any modules for the test project, they straight wrote the test. Not sure why is it looking for another Mymaps under test.

Comment: can you check, there is a `space` in your command between `my` and `maps`, which I think you want to name the project -- `dune init proj --kind=lib my maps`... it should have been `dune init proj --kind=lib mymaps`....

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the issue. the name of the test file should be the same as the name of the project. I renamed my tests file to "mymaps.ml" and then the error went away.

Comment: I'm more surprised that dune doesn't complain about having two projects with the same name. You might want to consider renaming the test project to `mymaps_test` instead.